# Corda - info about transaction size

Tags: blockchain, corda

I want to know if there is a way to get the dimension of the transactions of a node.

I know that there is the *NODE_TRANSACTIONS* table but I don't know how to query it. It is possible to do it via Corda API? there is another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the size of the transaction from `SignedTransaction.txBits.size`, for example from the `SignedTransaction` object returned when you sign the transaction or when you call `FinalityFlow`:

```
val finalTx = subFlow(FinalityFlow(signedTx, listOf(session))).txBits.size
```

To access the `NODE_TRANSACTION` table there are no direct APIs, but you can create a JDBC session from the `serviceHub`, for example:

```
serviceHub.jdbcSession().createStatement()
.execute("SELECT * FROM NODE_TRANSACTION WHERE XXXX;")
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, the solution "SignedTransaction.txBits.size" works (per single transaction), but is there any way to use the JDBC session and get the total transactions' size of a node? (e.g. I would like to know which is the transaction with the largest size)

Comment: @user10488162 you could store that information for each transaction in a separate table using JDBC session. Just an idea..

Comment: Ok! thank you very much for your feedback!